# Перезапуск js скрипта при повторном обращении

Tags: javascript, spa

Я хочу, что бы мой скрипт запускался каждый раз, при переходе на swipe.html. 
Но он грузится лишь первый раз. При повторном заходе на swipe.html он не выполняется и содержимое, управляемое из скрипта не отображается. Как это исправить?

```
    const ids = ['index', 'profile', 'swipe', 'swipe_ex'];

function showPage(pageId) {
    for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (pageId == ids[i]) {
            document.getElementById(pageId).style.display = "block";
            if (pageId != 'index')
                $('#' + pageId).load(pageId + '.html', function () {
                    if (pageId == 'swipe')
                        $.getScript("js/swipe.js");
                });
        } else {
            document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение заключалось в том, чтобы каждый раз при обращении к swipe.js вызывается метод.
js файл подключил в html, так как он не успевал погружаться при первом вызове через js.